# Populating amchart dynamically fetching data from mysql

Tags: mysql, dynamic, amcharts

I am trying to fetch records from `mysql` and render the data via `amchart`, but I am facing difficulty in doing so. I have written the following code which is not working. The query works fine but the problem is replacing the static (placeholder) data with the results of the query. Please suggest.

```
{

$selectdata="SELECT member_lhp, COUNT( * ) AS  'land_pattern' FROM hh_basic_info GROUP BY member_lhp";
$resdata=mysql_query($selectdata);

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var chartData = [
        <?php
            $count=0;
            while($rowdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($resdata))
            foreach($rowdata as $rows){
                $type= $rows['member_lhp'];
                $lp=$rows['land_pattern'];
                if($count++ > 0) echo ',';
        ?>
        {
            year: <?php echo $type;?>,
            income: <?php echo $lp;?>
        },
        <?php } ?>
    ];

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        // SERIAL CHART
        chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;
        chart.categoryField = "year";
        // this single line makes the chart a bar chart, 
        // try to set it to false - your bars will turn to columns                
        chart.rotate = true;
        // the following two lines makes chart 3D
        chart.depth3D = 20;
        chart.angle = 30;

        // AXES
        // Category
        var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
        categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
        categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
        categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
        categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
        categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";

        // value
        var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
        valueAxis.title = "Villagers - Land holding pattern";
        valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

        // GRAPH
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = "Income";
        graph.valueField = "income";
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.balloonText = "Land holding number in [[category]]:[[value]]";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillColors = "#bf1c25";
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        chart.addGraph(graph);

        // WRITE
        chart.write("chartdiv");
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? _"Arranging the dynamic data with that of the static data"_ is not at all clear. What happens, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to replace the static data with dynamic ones that are fetch from the database. The static data:

    {
     var chartData = [{
                year: 'Landless',
                income: 16
            }, {
                year: 'Marginal (upto 2.5 acre)',
                income: 7
            }, {
                year: 'Small (2.5 5 acre)',
                income: 6
            }, {
                year: 'Medium (5 - 12.5 acre)',
                income: 0
            }, {
                year: 'Large (12.5 acre - more)',
                income: 0
            }];
    }

Comment: looks like your already doing it dynamically the value for year needs to be placed inside quotes
`year: '<?php echo $type;?>',`

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance it looks like you may have included an extra comma after your curly bracket.  You are already adding a comma via the PHP if your count is greater than 0 so this would have been introducing a second, unnecessary one between each group of data.

You had the following...

```
    {
      year: <?php echo $type;?>,
      income: <?php echo $lp;?>
    },
```

try just having this instead...

```
    {
      year: <?php echo $type;?>,
      income: <?php echo $lp;?>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to parse in json format,
Just write

```
var newchartData= JSON.parse(chartData);
```

now assign `newcharData` to DataProvider,it should work.